# href not working in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have the following project structure:
[image]

My dispactcher-servlet.xml is as followings:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="31556926"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/WEB-INF/**" location="/WEB-INF/" cache-period="31556926"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />


<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

However the following href in my jsp does not work:

```
href="<c:url value="/WEB-INF/views/contact.html"/>"
```

I get a http 404 error saying requested resource is not found.

I also tried

```
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
href="${contextPath}/contact.html"/>"
```

But this also did not work:

The following works:

```
href="<c:url value="/resources/assets/css/contact.html"/>"
```

However I would need to create a copy of contact.html in resources/assets/css.

Why does the mapping /WEB-INF/views/contact.html not work?

Comment: WEB-INF is kind of secure directory and content of it usually resolved and not directly referred

Comment: What does the `href` look like in the generated HTML?

Comment: <a href="/ProjectName/WEB-INF/views/contact.html"